# MySQL collation and Glassfish default-charset encoding

Tags: java, mysql, linux, utf-8, glassfish

I have a Glassfish 4 and MySQL 5.5 running on my local machine. The database collation and Glassfish default-charset encoding is UTF-8. it works with no problem.

However, when I deploy this application on a VPS linux server I can't seem to save any record with UTF-8 character in it using the application. Ş becomes ? I checked my SQL server's collation and glassfish encoding default-charset they are all UTF-8!

Is there something I am missing? Only difference is that my local runs Windows 7 OS and the VPS is a Linux Ubuntu machine!

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I had to add these lines to my.cnf I guess MySQL Win version and Linux version come with different default configuration

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8

[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_turkish_ci

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8
```